# How fast does this planet have to rotate to have gravity thrice as strong at the poles?

Tags: planets, gravity, day-night

For those of you who have read *mission of gravity,* or researched Saturn’s equatorial bulge, you will know that the faster a planet rotates, the greater the “flattening” effect it’s rotation has. This means that planets (like Saturn) which rotate very quickly have a “bulge” at the equator, reminiscent of a hole-less donut or a football that’s been stepped on. And the greater this “bulge” is, the greater the difference is between the surface gravity at the poles and the gravity at the equator.

Now, I have a terrestrial world which, like Saturn, has a tidal bulge. This is a terrestrial planet 1.6 times the mass of earth, with a density of around 5.5 g/cm<sup>3</sup>. It’s axial tilt is 24 degrees.

I would like this planet to have a gravitational attraction of about 40% earth-*g* at the equator, and 120% earth-*g* at the poles. How fast, then, would it have to rotate in order to create this difference?

If there is any information needed to work this out that I have neglected, please tell me! The above information is all I have on this planet so far, so additional data can easily be added.

Comment: You don't even need to have a bulge. The difference in angular speed between the equator and pole is sufficient to reduce the apparent gravity.

Comment: With the gravity force at the pole three times as large, the equatorial bulge is going to be non-negligible. The simple calculations provided in the two answers posted now are going to be wrong by a significant amount.  I'm busy trying to set up the calculation but it's evading me.

Comment: @Andrew, you don't need a bulge, but you also can't avoid a bulge in the real world.

Comment: A football that's been stepped on?  You must be referring to a non-American football... :-D

Comment: Coriolis effects are going to be interesting. Variable with lattitude, and evere.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Coriolis effects vary with latitude on Earth anyway. A planet with a larger equatorial bulge should actually have less variation in the magnitude of Coriolis forces across latitudes, since the curvature of the surface is more concentrated near the equator, and stays flatter for a larger distance around the poles.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Are you sure it goes that way? I am not an expert, of course, but as far as I know, coriolis effect would be stronger on a flattened planet because the linear speed difference between latitudes is even bigger than on a spherical planet.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley With an ~= 4 hour rotation period and weight changing by about 3:1 and 2/3 weight being "spun off you" at the equator: Coriolis at equator is mind bending. At poles its essentially zero.  Rate of change varies from that of a sphere (as you note) but pole to equator change would be astounding.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You've got it backwards--Coriolis effects are *weakest* at the equator. Yes, the total difference in strength between poles and equator would be larger, because the maximum strength of the effect is larger, but over most of the planet, the gradient would be reduced due to flattening, So yeah, it varies with latitude... but that's not unusual.

Comment: @JaniMiettinen Consider the limiting case--a perfectly flat disk. Coriolis forces are completely uniform across the surface of a disk, because the difference in tangential speed bewteen equally-spaced points on a radius is always the same, suddenly dropping to zero exactly on the edge. The more a planet bulges, getting less sphere-like and more disk-like, the more it concentrates the gradient in the region near the equator, and makes the rest of the surface more uniform.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Yes, it is more uniform... but... how does that matter?

Comment: @JaniMiettinen Because I was addressing a claim that there would be more variation in Coriolis forces. Over most of the planet, there wouldn't--the forces would be uniformly stronger, but not more variable, because all the variation is concentrated towards the equator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Referring to [the formula for how much bulging occurs for a given speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_bulge#Formulation) (up to on the first order but it's good enough), we have that the difference in polar and equatorial radii relative to the mean radius $a = \frac{a_e + a_e + a_p}{3}$ is that $$\frac{a_e - a_p}{a} = \frac{5}{4} \frac{\omega^2 a^3}{GM}$$.
The only other constraint on $a_e, a_p$ we have is the volume of the planet derived from the mass and density, $\rho \cdot \frac{4 \pi}{3} a_e^2 a_p = M$. And what we want from the equatorial acceleration and polar acceleration is that $$3 g_e = 3 \left( \frac{GM}{a_e^2} - a_e \omega^2 \right) = q_p = \frac{GM}{a^2_p}$$
ignoring the non-spherical components of gravity. We can't decide the exact values as

We know from the volume constraint that $a_p = \frac{a_V^3}{a_e^2}$, where $a_V$ is the radius of the spherical planet. This turns the other two into an equation on $a_e$ and $\omega$. For the gravity magnitude relation, we get a quadratic on $a_e^3$, so $$a_e = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-3\omega^2 + \sqrt{9\omega^4 + 12 \frac{G^2M^2}{a^6_V}}}{2 \frac{GM}{a^6_V}}} \text{   or   } \omega^2 = \frac{GM}{a_e^3} \left( 1 - \frac{a_e^6}{3a_V^6}\right)$$

Let $a_e = f a_V$ and we get the final monster formula when subbing into the bulge relation, $$\frac{3f^3 - 3}{2 f^3 + 1} = \left(1 - \frac{f^3}{3} \right) \frac{5}{4} \frac{\left(\frac{2}{3}f^3 + \frac{1}{3}\right)^3}{f^9}$$

This is an absolute monster of a polynomial, a quintic  of $f^3$ and definitely not solvable by analytical methods. By graph, the answer is roughly $1.16017$. We could get more decimals, but we have enough error from our approximations.
[image: graph of the functions]

We thus get our variables as
$$ \begin{align}
a_v &= \sqrt[3]{\frac{3M}{4 \pi \rho} } = 7458 \text{ km} \\
a_e &= f \cdot a_V = 8652 \text{ km} \\
a_p &= f^{-2} \cdot a_V = 5541 \text{ km} \\
\omega &= \sqrt{\frac{4 \pi \rho G}{3 f^3} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{3} f^6\right) } = 4.293 \cdot 10^{-4} \text{Hz} \\
\implies T &= \frac{2 \pi }{\omega} = 4 \text{ hours } 3 \text{ minutes } 56 \text{ seconds}
\end{align}$$

Yeah that's fast. Definitely beyond the range of the approximations taken here.

Edit : BTW the gravitational acceleration at equator is 0.707 G and at the poles is 2.12G. If you scale your radius by $s$ while keeping density fixed, mass changes by $s^3$, while acceleration changes by $s$, but the time period remains fixed. So to get 0.4G at equator and 1.2 at poles at the same density, the planet must have a mass of $0.3 M_\oplus$, radii of $a_V = 4262 \text{ km}, a_e = 3166 \text{ km}, a_p = 4944 \text{ km}$.

Comment: As I get it, you cannot ignore that the planet is aspherical when calculating gravity on the pole, let alone in the center. So while your answer could be good enough for the first approximation, there had to be more to do with calculating exact gravity to an ellipsoid. (I don't remember if an inverse square function if integrated over an ellipsoid would return some pretty looking value, and if not, you'r in a world of too high maths for the entire Stack Exchange)

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that getting an exact answer for this is sufficiently complex, and dependent on compositional detials of the specific planet in question, that even Hal Clement got the answer wrong by a factor of about 3 when writing Mission of Gravity.

Comment: @Vesper There was a decomposition till the first order in terms of Legendre Polynomials on cos(polar angle), the standard multi-pole expansion, but I really didn't feel up to calculating that.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Of course, all possible calculations are dead in the water if you don't consider the planet to be uniform. AFAIK the core being slightly denser than the crust and mantle, which is the part that gets ellipsoidal, is a decently large factor in proper calculation, but at the end of the day they introduce a coefficient on the order of unity in our answer.

Comment: @VaradMahashabde Not *all* possible calculations; it is possible, after all, to do a finite-element numerical simulation to produce arbitrarily accurate results with arbitrary variations in density--you just have to be willing to throw a large enough amount of human effort and computer time at it!

Answer (score 0):

At the poles the centrifugal force due to rotation is null, thus your question can be reworded as:

> given a planet with surface gravity of 12 $m/s^2$, what is the rotation speed which would give a net gravity at the equator of 4 $m/s^2$?

The net gravity at the equator can be calculated as $g_{net}=g-r\omega^2$.

On a first approximation you can use the same radius for the pole and the equator. A more refined model would require accounting for the bulge and use different radia.

Comment: That first approximation will be *extremely bad* in this case, as there *will be* a significant departure from sphericality, and you have to account for the different polar and equatorial radii.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration due to gravity is given by $g = \frac{GM}{r^2}$. The apparent centrifugal acceleration on the surface is given by $c = \omega^2 r$. You want $g-c$ to be one-third of $g$, so $c=\frac{2}{3}g$:

$\omega^2 r = \frac23 \left(\frac{GM}{r^2}\right)$

$\implies \omega = \sqrt{\dfrac{2GM}{3r^3}}$

Comment: This is incorrect because the planet's radius at the equator is different than at the poles. Normally, this difference is so small it can be ignored for first-order approximations, but in this case I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

> would like this planet to have a gravitational attraction of about 40% earth-g at the equator, and 120% earth-g at the poles. How fast, then, would it have to rotate in order to create this difference?

You can't.

The shape of the planet will be one in which the surface gravity along the surface is equal at the poles and at the equator.

If you spin it faster, the planet will just bulge further.

The material strength of a reasonably large planet required to have not differ significantly from this is simply insane.

(by "gravity", I mean the sum of the gravitational attraction of the planet plus the inertial effects of rotation).

Comment: Wrong for Earth at the very least, Earth has freefall acceleration difference of about 0.065 m/s^2 at sea level for poles vs equator. So, spinning a planet up could produce the required effect. After all, if a planet is about to get torn apart by its own spin, would it not have zero effective freefall acceleration on its equator? And on the pole, it's nonzero by construction.

Comment: @Vesper your comment is nonsense. the definition of a planet is it forms its own shape under the force of gravity. Now rocks aren't perfectly liquid, and there are other forces, so there can be an imbalance of a few percent, which the answer has not mentioned.  If there were any significant imbalance, the body fails to meet the definition of a planet

Comment: @camelccc The surface of a planet must follow an approximate surface of *equal potential* for its own self-gravity. That is very much not the same thing as a surface of *equal force*.

Comment: @camelccc No, I think Vesper is right.  Take a gravitational+rotational force field.  At equipotential a fluid can be at rest in this field.  But the force of gravity at each spot is the derivative of this field; that derivative need not be equal over the equipotential surface.  The derivative is even normal to the equipotential surface; hence, if you froze the liquid, a ball bearing wouldn't roll on the surface.  No need for the body to be rigid at all.

Comment: @yakk this is nonsense, if the force is not equal, so is the pressure of the liquid under the surface not equal, and if the body cant be considered a liquid, its not a planet. Obviously the planets surface must also be an equipotential. which implies no lateral forces so no pressure gradients else the liquid will move. In reality, any such body with this level of spin will fly apart, likely recombining to give a planet with rings

Comment: @camelccc Planets are bodies large enough that the force of gravity makes the solids act mostly like liquids (they flow into a sphere).  I'm just using a liquid to remove the remaining tiny (at planetary scales) rigidity of solids.  And the liquid body will fall apart only if the spin outpaces the force of gravity, which is not under consideration here (besides Vesper's smart remark about the planet flying apart in the limit of extreme spin).  I think you are confused.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @Yakk the definition of a planet is a body large enough that it forms its own shape under gravity. If this is not possible the planet simply can't form in the first place  And  the force of gravity must be approximately the same everywhere, or the planet will find a lower energy state with a new shape such that it is. The surface of the planet must also be an equipotential, barring minor things like mountains. IF you have a planet there the gravity at the pole is 2x that of the equator, the planet is going to spin out into a ring - fast

Comment: @camelccc You are making claims without justification that don't follow from your previous statements.  Maybe because you have unmentioned justifications.  The claim is that a "fat disk" planet spinning fast can (a) have a surface at equipotential, and (b) have radically different surface gravities at the pole and equator due to the spin.  This planet does not have the rotational energy to fully defeat gravity, so it cannot "spin out into a ring".  There is no perturbation that leads to a lower energy state, so it cannot change form to find a lower energy state.

Comment: If you spin this planet up a bit more, yes, it ends up having enough energy for its equator to tear off and form a ring (which steals angular momentum).  You seem to be claiming that you cannot reach a (rotational + gravitational force) factor of 2 difference before this happens, without you stating a justification why.  You might be correct, but you aren't justifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen H. Dole, in *Habitable Planets For Man* (1964):

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Discusses the requirements necessary for world to be habitable for human beings (and also for multicellular land animals with the same environmental requirements as humans).

Other scientific discussions of planetary habitability are for liquid water using life in general, and not for humans and lifeforms with the same environmental requirements in particular.

On pages 41 to 46 the cases of rapidly rotating planets which become oblate in shape.

And on pages 58 to 61 Dole discussed limits on the planetary rotation rate of human habitable planets. Dole believed that a planet would be rotating too fast when the surface gravity at the equator dropped to zero and matter was lost from the planet, or when the shape of the surface became unstable and axial symmetry was lost.  Dole believed that for planets in he size range of Human habitable worlds, a rotation so fast that a single rotation took 2 to 3 hours would result in an unstable planetary surface.

So you should check whether a rotation rate fast enough for to there to be a surface gravity at the poles 3 times as high as at the equator would be safe and stable for the planet.